# Itextsharp "RowSpan" missing? "no definition for rowspan"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I am using iTextsharp to generate a table and print in pdf formant. 
I am able to use colspan but when i try to use rowspan on PdfPCell it is unable to recognize it. I get "no definition for rowspan"

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
            table.WidthPercentage = 90f;
            //set column widths
            int[] firstTablecellwidth = { 20, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10,10,10,10 };
            table.SetWidths(firstTablecellwidth);

            doc1.Add(p1);
            table.AddCell("Name :");
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Star Diamonds"));
cell.Colspan = 8;///this works fine
cell.Rowspan = 4; //does not contain definition for rowspan
            table.AddCell(cell);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/2060638.aspx?I+want+to+merge+cells+of+same+value+in+the+first+column+in+itextsharp+for+asp+net) forum question discussing the different iTextSharp versions. It should work in the latest iTextsharp version.

Comment: Links may go dead. Please copy the essential part of the solution to your answer, so future visitors of StackOverflow may still benefit from your answer. A good answer gets upvotes, an answer with only a dead link gets downvotes.

Comment: thanks, upgrading to newer version helped. 
See if you can answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/38158112/2064292

Answer (score 1):

I remember that `Rowspan` wasn't defined for `PdfPTable` when I wrote the first edition of "iText in Action". I also remember that `Rowspan` was defined when I wrote the second edition of that book (that was actually a rewrite).

Given your claim that you get "no definition for Rowspan", the logical conclusion would be that you're using a mighty old version of iTextSharp. I suggest that you update to iTextSharp 5.5.9 if you want to use the code in your question, or that you upgrade to iText 7 for C# if you're just starting with your project.

Your claim is contradicted by many other answers if you'd say that you're using a recent version of iTextSharp:

- [Create PDF in asp.net using c# with row span & colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199553/create-pdf-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp-with-row-span-colspan)
- [How to merge rows with same value in PDF using iTextSharp, in ASP.NET and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288804/how-to-merge-rows-with-same-value-in-pdf-using-itextsharp-in-asp-net-and-c)
- [pdfpCell.Rowspan in itextsharp not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124504/pdfpcell-rowspan-in-itextsharp-not-work-properly)
- [iText(Sharp): tables with headers and subheaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748444)
- ...

Comment: you are right i was using older version. Its fixed now.+1

Comment: See if you can answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/38158112/2064292

Comment: When you post a question, you can *accept* a correct answer by clicking on the check mark near the score of the answer. The answer to [Unable to change font in iTextsharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158112) is rather trivial.